# How do I get response data out of the axios mock file and into the test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

I’m having trouble with the placement of my response data for an axios mock. If I include the data in the mock file, the test passes. If I include it in the test with `axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValue();` it doesn’t. I don’t want the response in the mock file because that file needs to work with all axios tests.

If I include my response in the axios mock file like this, things work as expected.

```js
// __mocks__/axios.js
export default {
  create: jest.fn(() => ({
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data: {
        data: [
          {
            label: 'Started',
            value: 'started',
            type: 'Milestone',
          },
          {
            label: 'Detected',
            value: 'detected',
            type: 'Milestone',
          },
          {
            label: 'Acknowledged',
            value: 'acknowledged',
            type: 'Milestone',
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
    interceptors: {
      request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
      response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
    },
  })),
  get: jest.fn(),
};
```

My test file:

```js
// Condition.spec.js
test('fetches and displays data', async () => {
  axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValue();

  const { container } = render(
    <Condition {...props} />
  );
  await wait(() => expect(container.textContent).toContain('Current milestone is Acknowledged'));
  expect(container).toBeDefined();
});
```

If I remove it from the mock file and place it in the test, it fails:

```js
// __mocks__/axios.js
export default {
  create: jest.fn(() => ({
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
    interceptors: {
      request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
      response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
    },
  })),
  get: jest.fn(),
};
```

```js
// Condition.spec.js
test('fetches and displays data', async () => {
  axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValue({
    data: {
      data: [
        {
          label: 'Started',
          value: 'started',
          type: 'Milestone',
        },
        {
          label: 'Detected',
          value: 'detected',
          type: 'Milestone',
        },
        {
          label: 'Acknowledged',
          value: 'acknowledged',
          type: 'Milestone',
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  const { container } = render(
    <Condition {...props} />
  );
  await wait(() => expect(container.textContent).toContain('Current milestone is Acknowledged'));
  expect(container).toBeDefined();
});
```

How do I get my response data out of the mock file and into the test itself?

Comment: How is `axiosMock` defined?

Comment: Just an import of axios: `import axiosMock from 'axios';`

Comment: So you're mocking the `axios` module too somewhere, like `jest.mock('axios')`?

Comment: The `__mocks__/axios.js` file above is the axios mock.

Comment: Do you need the `__mocks__/axios.js` file even after moving the mock data? Otherwise, delete it and use `jest.mock('axios')` instead to mock `axios`.

Comment: @BrandonDurham I think you might not be using it correctly, could you please share codesandbox with failing test? Most likely you will need to use `axios-mock-adapter` to mock axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
import firehydrantAPI from '../../helpers/firehydrantAPI'

jest.mock('../../helpers/firehydrantAPI');

const data = {
  "data":[
    {
      "label":"Started",
      "value":"started",
      "type":"Milestone"
    },
    {
      "label":"Detected",
      "value":"detected",
      "type":"Milestone"
    },
    {
      "label":"Acknowledged",
      "value":"acknowledged",
      "type":"Milestone"
    }
  ]
}

firehydrantAPI.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data }));
```

Comment: No dice. Sorry.

Comment: data is undefined

Comment: Have you declared constant data as I declared above? I have updated my answer, please check once again.

Comment: I did. It’s the correct data but the component never receives it in the response.